# pause and resume swf file using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to pause the swf file while user close the jsp page and if the user when ever comes in that page video must be play where it could be paused. i don't have any idea for how to do this.can any one give me the idea to do this.i am using jsp,jquery,javascript concepts in my web project

Thanks in advance

I am using following code for play the swf file in jsp page

```
<object width='500' height='500' data='"+op+".swf' border='10' style='border-color: BLUE'></object>
```

Comment: will this link help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905267/swfobject-play-pause-stop

Comment: @GeorgeRosario it is not ordinary pause play. i need to pause the swf file until user visit the page next time and continue the play